# How to use waterline outside sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to use Waterline in my express application but how do I configure the database connection? I would like to use sails-mongo as an adapter but I'm not sure how to do it. Can any one help me with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of using Waterline with Express in the Waterline Repo: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/example/express/express-example.js

Comment: Thanks just saw that also and I feel stupid of not looking at the exapmle folder :)